# Parallel threads stopping each others

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want my application to have the following behaviour : While the application (server) is waiting for a message from another application (client), I want to be able to exit if it is too long with an input from the user.

Therefore, I must launch two threads from a third one:

1. `WaitForClientMessage`
2. `WaitForUserInput`

Using `pthread`, I imagined that I can call each thread and give them the id of the other, so if they end, they would cancel the other one. But now I see it won't works.

How do this? I guess it is simple because such behaviour is often seen, but I don't know how get it work.

**EDIT**
Here is some general code which described what I imagined.

```
void main_thread( void)
{
    void * thread_rtn_val;

    /* Parallel threads */
    pthread_t thread_WaitForClientMessage;
    pthread_t thread_WaitForUserInput;

    /* Run Threads */
    pthread_create(&thread_WaitForClientMessage, NULL, run_window, (void *)thread_sdp);
    pthread_create(&thread_WaitForUserInput, NULL, run_client, (void *)arg_array);
}


void run_window( void)
{

    /* Refresh screen and watch for user input */
    for(...)
    {
        if(user press enter)
        {
            phtread_cancel(thread_WaitForClientMessage)
        }
    }
}


void run_client( void)
{
    /* Wait for client message */
    recv()...
    phtread_cancel(thread_WaitForUserInput)
}
```

Comment: Can you please include your current code and the appropriate language tag?

Comment: is the client message coming in on a socket while the user input is coming in from console?  you could probably use `select` or `poll` in a single thread with a suitable timeout value.

Comment: @ Marvin I will add some code
@ NG. Here the threads are on higher layers and I don't want to modify the sockets functions already defined.

Comment: you should probably use a pthread_cond_t as a way to signal your threads as needing to close.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try a nonblocking flag for your function recv() ?